# How to show google popup confirm dialog with angular7?

Tags: angular7

I am trying to display the chrome  popup confirm dialog after a modification done when i try to leave  to go another url (route) in my application .

[image]

I add this code :

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) beforeUnload($event) {
     $event.returnValue = '';
  }
```

but when i try to move to another route i didn't get any confirm dialog.
I'm working with angular7. How to resolve that? any example ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides Guards for Route events. Based on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) of CanDeactivate Guard, you can show confirmation dialog before leave from page.

```
  @Injectable()
    class CanDeactivateExample implements CanDeactivate<YourComponent> {

      canDeactivate(
        component: YourComponent,
        currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
        nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>{

         if(component.isModified){
          return confirm('Are you sure to leave from page?');
        }
        return true;

      }
    }
```

To use it, you should edit your routes like:

```
imports:[
...
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '<path>',
        component: YourComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateExample]
      }
    ])
]
```

Also Guards are injectables, so you need to provide it at your module which you want to use inside.

```
provides: [..., CanDeactivateExample]
```